# Null Pointer when trying to retrieve user details from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception

In my Android app, I have a database repository to contact Firebase Realtime Database and a service layer with some methods. My SaveUserProfile method works but I keep getting a null pointer on my GetUserFromUid.

The 'user' object it returns is null and I don't know why. The node in my DB is called "users" (all lowercase) and I want to retrieve a user as a model via their userId and display the name and email onscreen.

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

My DbContext:

```
public class DbContext implements IDbContext {

User user = null;
Context context;
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

 public DbContext(Context context){
   super();
   this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void AddUserAccount(User user1) {
    databaseUsers.child(user1.userId).setValue(user1);
}

@Override
public User GetUserFromFirebase(String uid) {
   databaseUsers.child(uid)
           .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
    return user;
}
```

My DbService:

```
public class DbService implements IDbService {

//instance of DbContext for firebase handling
private DbContext dbContext;

public DbService(Context context){
    super();
    dbContext = new DbContext(context);
}

@Override
public User SaveUserProfile(User u) {

    dbContext.AddUserAccount(u);

    return u;
}

@Override
public User GetUserFromUid(String uid) {
    User user = dbContext.GetUserFromFirebase(uid);
    return user;
}
```

My User model:

```
public class User {

public String userId;
public String name;
public String email;
public String account;

//constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
public User(){
}

public User(String userId, String name, String email, String account) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.account = account;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAccount() {
    return account;
}

public void setAccount(String account) {
    this.account = account;
}
```

My activity where I want to display the users' details:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//tag
private static final String TAG = DetailsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

//firebase auth
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

//variables
private TextView inputName, inputEmail;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private String userId;
public String currentUserAccount;
public String teacherAccountNav = "Teacher";
public User userDetails;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    inputName = findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);

   

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    assert user != null;
    userId = user.getUid();

   
    getUserDetails(userId);
    inputName.setText(userDetails.name);
    inputEmail.setText(userDetails.email);
}

public User getUserDetails(String uid){
    DbService dbService = new DbService(this);
    userDetails = dbService.GetUserFromUid(uid);
    return userDetails;
}
```

**EDITS BELOW**

My callback:

```
public interface Callback {
void myResponseCallback(User user);
}
```

My EDITED DbContext:

public class DbContext implements IDbContext {

```
User user = null;
Context context;
DatabaseReference databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

public DbContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void AddUserAccount(User user1) {
    databaseUsers.child(user1.userId).setValue(user1);
}

@Override
public void GetUserFromFirebase(String uid, final Callback callback) {
    databaseUsers.child(uid)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    callback.myResponseCallback(user);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

}
```

My EDITED DbService:

```
public class DbService implements IDbService {

//instance of DbContext for firebase handling
public DbContext dbContext;

public DbService(Context context){
    super();
    dbContext = new DbContext(context);
}

@Override
public User SaveUserProfile(User u) {

    dbContext.AddUserAccount(u);

    return u;
}

@Override
public User GetUserFromUid(String uid) {
    final User[] user1 = {new User()};
    dbContext.GetUserFromFirebase(uid, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void myResponseCallback(User user) {
            user1[0] = user;
        }
    });
    return user1[0];
}
```

My EDITED Activity:

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    inputName = findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);

    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    //reference to 'users' node
    mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users");

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    assert user != null;
    userId = user.getUid();


    getUserFromFirebase(userId);

}

public void getUserFromFirebase(String uid){
    userDetails = (new DbService(this)).GetUserFromUid(uid);
    inputEmail.setText(userDetails.email);
    inputName.setText(userDetails.name);
}
```

Debug BEFORE edits:

[image: debug before edits]

Debug AFTER edits:

[image: debug after edits]

As you can see from the debug, before the callback interface, userDetails was null. After the interface implementation, userDetails is not null but all of the object values are null. I don't know why this is as they are filled in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: [because it isn't synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks. Could you be a bit more specific to my code? I don't really understand your link, sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: my example gives you a complete tutorial on how to implement it yourself, if you're stuck along the way you're more than welcome to update your question here with what you've tried so far

Comment: @a_local_nobody I think I've implemented your solution. I've added my edits above along with some screenshots of my debug. As you can see, the userDetails object is being filled but all the values are null. These are not null in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: `return user1[0];` this will also not work, because the values you receive are only returned to you through the callback pattern, inside `GetUserFromFirebase` will be the only place you have a reference to the user object, you're basically returning nothing, that's what it seems

Comment: `myResponseCallback` and the service calls you're making to firebase don't execute top down like normal calls, because they're callbacks/service calls

Comment: that's why you can use the callback pattern to give you access to these response as they become available, but these objects will only be available to you inside the callbacks, anywhere else _probably_ haven't been returned yet, because it's a service call, we don't know how long it'll take to perform this operation

Comment: my advice would be to simply get one working example first inside the onDataChange of a method and then afterwards you can start to break it up into smaller methods, if you want to

Comment: for now, putting everything inside onDataChange will make sure that your code works, don't worry about return types or values for now, just handle the data as it comes and as you expect it to, after that you can start to break it up when you start to understand how it works

Comment: @a_local_nobody I have it working in my DetailsActivity with code that is verbatim to my original GetUserFromFirebase method, it's only when I try to split it up that it breaks. I have to implement a repository and service layer to make the service code unit testable.